# Gnome: Video drivers on Dell XPS 9550 with 4K UHD screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi

This laptop has an i7 processor and a discrete Nvidia GTX 960M card. I'm trying to run Gnome Shell. Has anyone got this working really well? And if so, how?

My research/trials on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, installed in UEFI mode. Note: stock Ubuntu with Unity works fine with/without proprietary drivers.

### Intel/Nouveau

The nouveau drivers work for everything (i.e. I get Gnome up with the full resolution, touch works) except HDMI. When I plug in a FHD external monitor (VGA or HDMI), *either* I get what looks like a proper image on the external screen but with a flashy-mostly-black laptop display, *or* I get static images on both screens and a complete hang that you have to hard-boot from.

### Nvidia 361.28

Both the 'tested' and the 'updates' versions work the same way: they don't.

On booting I get a console screen in UHD that flashes on and off and does not accept keyboard input, most of the time.

### Hybrid: Gnome Shell installed on main Ubuntu image/lightdm

Gnome shell runs with both intel and nvidia graphics if it is started by lightdm, however it still kills the system if an external monitor is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the intel driver from SNA to UXA helped quite a bit. No more weird artefacts, though still some freezing when switching modes.

I had a similar experience with the `nvidia-361` driver.  I did get it working on a external HDMI monitor, but it was not always reliable.

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

Add this to `xorg` config by adding to a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`